# Why does this array indexing in numpy work?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've got some numpy 2d arrays:

x, of shape(N,T)

W, of shape(V,D)

they are described as the following:

"Minibatches of size N where each sequence has length T. We assume a vocabulary of V words, assigning each to a vector of dimension D."(This is a question from cs231 A3.)

I want an output array of shape(N, T, D), where i can match the N elements to the desired vectors.

First I came out with the solution using a loop to run through all the elements in the first row of x:

```
    for n in range(N):
        out[n, :, :] = W[x[n, :]]
```

Then I go on to experiment with the second solution:

```
    out = W[x]
```

Both solutions gave me the right answer, but why does the second solution work? Why can I index a 3d array in a 2d array?

Comment: can you give real examples of x and W? Or at least the dimensions in real numbers?

Comment: An example will be : N, T, V, D = 2, 4, 5, 3. With this example the second solution become (2,4,3) = (5,3)[(2,4)]...and I think I figure it our haha! THX!